# Data binding setting colors

Tags: android, data-binding

I try to use ternary operator to change the textcolor of button.
Something like that: here is the xml.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionButton"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:backgroundTint="@{selected ? R.color.white : R.color.turquoise}"
    android:text="@{selected ? &quot;Selected &quot; : &quot;Select &quot;}"
    android:textColor="@{selected ? @color/white : @color/turquoise}"
    android:onClick="@{(view) -> handler.selectClick(view)}"/>
```

But the colors are not set correctly. I get some wierd purple colors instead.

I tried

```
<import type="com.myapp.R" />
android:textColor="@{selected ? R.color.white : R.color.turquoise}"
```

with same result.
How should I do it?

Comment: did you check in turquoise color you set right color code ?

Comment: Yes. The colors are fine. android:textColor="@color/turquoise" works as needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first variant should work fine. You can refer to "Resources" chapter of [this doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#Resources).
Here is a full working example.

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="foo">#fff</color>
    <color name="bar">#000</color>
</resources>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable name="selected" type="boolean" />
        <variable name="button2" type="String" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_a"
            android:onClick="switchColor"
            android:text="Click me"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_b"
            android:textColor="@{selected ? @color/foo : @color/bar}"
            android:text="@{button2}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**ActivityMain.class**

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    MainActivityBinding mBinding;
    boolean mSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
        mBinding.setButton2("Don't click me please!");
    }

    public void switchColor(View view) {
        mBinding.setSelected(mSelected = !mSelected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi maybe I am too late but here is one more way of setting colours:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/mcvProductItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="@{insuranceProduct.active()}"
    android:focusable="@{insuranceProduct.active()}"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@{insuranceProduct.active() ? context.getColor(R.color.white) : context.getColor(R.color.bg_grey)}"
    android:onClick="@{(view) -> productItemClickListener.selectProduct(view,insuranceProduct)}"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
 </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Basicly I used the context to get colors resources. Hope it helps.